# azure emulator not accepting client certificates

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, client-certificates

I'm trying to perform client-side authentication in an Azure Web API service. I believe I'm correctly attaching a certificate to the client request, but the certificate is coming up null on the service end. This is how I'm sending in a client request (I've also tried the HttpClient with handler, with similar results):

```
// connectionUri points to my service
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionUri);
var cert = GetCert(); // this isn't null, i've checked
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
req.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
using (var readStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd());
}
```

On the service end, I'm handling the requests as follows:
(WebApiConfig.cs)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // "mycontroller" is an example, it never even gets to the controller
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "controller", "api/{action}", new { controller = "mycontroller" },
            null, new Validator());
    }
}
```

And the validator is defined as follows:

```
public class Validator
{
    // ...
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                HttpRequestMessage req, CancellationToken tok)
    {
        if (req.GetClientCertificate() == null)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               req.CreateErrorResponse(
                   HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "NULL CERT"), tok);
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
               req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, "YES"), tok);
        }
    }
}
```

While `GetCert()` (a function I wrote) returns the correct certificate (I've checked its thumbprint, it definitely exists), `req.GetClientCertificate()` always returns null. I've setup the ssl configuration on the service according to [this article](http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/using-client-certificates), and since I'm using the same certificate (it's a real signed certificate) for the server and the client (since I'm just testing this locally), and the intended purpose includes "Client Authentication," I don't think the server is rejecting the certificate because the certificate is invalid.

I'm reasonably certain the azure emulator (as well as the actual azure service; I've tried deploying to azure with similar results. I've uploaded the certificate to azure, by the way) is rejecting the client's certificate for whatever reason, though. What options might I be missing that would cause it to do that?